# Comparison of a Dataframe column values with a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider this Dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
                   'B': [10, 15, 20, 25, 30,35],
                   'C': [100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350]})
```

This is the code to get values of column C, where it is the first row of each group (Column A):

```
firsts = df.groupby('A').first()['C']
```

So first will be: `(100, 200, 300)`.

Now I want to add new column which it will be `1` if value of column C for row is in `firsts` otherwise it will be `0`.

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 100 | 1 |
| 1 | 15 | 150 | 0 |
| 2 | 20 | 200 | 1 |
| 2 | 25 | 250 | 0 |
| 3 | 30 | 300 | 1 |
| 3 | 35 | 350 | 0 |

I used this:

```
df['D'] = df['C'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x in firsts else 0)
```

But the output is:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 100 | 0 |
| 1 | 15 | 150 | 0 |
| 2 | 20 | 200 | 0 |
| 2 | 25 | 250 | 0 |
| 3 | 30 | 300 | 0 |
| 3 | 35 | 350 | 0 |

I appreciate if anyone explain why my solution is wrong and what is actual solution to this problem?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use `isin` method:

```
df['D'] = df.C.isin(firsts).astype(int)

df
#   A   B   C   D
#0  1   10  100 1
#1  1   15  150 0
#2  2   20  200 1
#3  2   25  250 0
#4  3   30  300 1
#5  3   35  350 0
```

---

The reason your approach fails is that python `in` operator check the index of a Series instead of the values, the same as how a dictionary works:

```
firsts
#A
#1    100
#2    200
#3    300
#Name: C, dtype: int64

1 in firsts
# True

100 in firsts
# False

2 in firsts
# True

200 in firsts
# False
```

Modifying your method as follows works:

```
firstSet = set(firsts)
df['C'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x in firstSet else 0)

#0    1
#1    0
#2    1
#3    0
#4    1
#5    0
#Name: C, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR:**

```
df['newColumn'] = np.where((df.compareColumn.isin(yourlist)), TrueValue, FalseValue)
```

---

Another one-step method would be to use [`np.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy-where) and [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html#pandas-dataframe-isin).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
                   'B': [10, 15, 20, 25, 30,35],
                   'C': [100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350]})

df['D'] = np.where((df.B.isin(firsts)), 1, 0)
```

We use the return from [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html#pandas-dataframe-isin) as the condition in [`np.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy-where) to return either

- `1` when `True`
- `0` when `False`

and assign them to a new column in the same dataframe `df['D']`.

**Note:** `np.where` allows more complex conditions with [bitwise](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/operators) operators and replacement cases,  i.e. 'bypass' on `False`

```
df['col1'] = np.where(((df['col1'] == df['col2']) &
                       (~df['col1'].str.startswith('r'))),
                       'replace', df['col1'])
```

---

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it in one step using `.transform('first')`:

```
In [280]: df['D'] = df.groupby('A')['C'].transform('first').eq(df['C']).astype(np.int8)

In [281]: df
Out[281]:
   A   B    C  D
0  1  10  100  1
1  1  15  150  0
2  2  20  200  1
3  2  25  250  0
4  3  30  300  1
5  3  35  350  0
```

**Explanation:** `GroupBy.transform('func')` returns us a vector with the same length as the original DF with applied `func`

```
In [14]: df.groupby('A')['C'].transform('first')
Out[14]:
0    100
1    100
2    200
3    200
4    300
5    300
Name: C, dtype: int64

In [15]: df.groupby('A')['C'].transform('max')
Out[15]:
0    150
1    150
2    250
3    250
4    350
5    350
Name: C, dtype: int64

In [16]: df.groupby('A')['C'].transform('min')
Out[16]:
0    100
1    100
2    200
3    200
4    300
5    300
Name: C, dtype: int64

In [17]: df.groupby('A')['C'].transform('mean')
Out[17]:
0    125
1    125
2    225
3    225
4    325
5    325
Name: C, dtype: int64

In [18]: df.groupby('A')['C'].transform('sum')
Out[18]:
0    250
1    250
2    450
3    450
4    650
5    650
Name: C, dtype: int64
```

Comment: May you please explain what 'transform('first')' does here? (I couldn't find simple explanation for transform)

Comment: @MehrdadSComputer, i've added an explanation - i hope it's clearer now

Comment: Thanks. So it's somehow like 'apply' function.

Answer (score -1):

firsts is pandas series , so when we use in to search for value then it will search that value in index list to solve this we can convert firsts to list or array

```
%timeit df['D'] = df['C'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x in firsts.values else 0)
```

314 µs ± 17.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

**or**

```
%timeit df['D'] = df['C'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x in list(firsts) else 0)
```

301 µs ± 11.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

**or**

```
%timeit df['D'] = list(map(lambda x: 1 if x in list(firsts) else 0,list(df['C'])))
```

27.6 µs ± 1.02 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)